# How can I eliminate wxListCtrl flicker while scrolling?

Tags: scroll, wxwidgets, flicker, doublebuffered

I'm using wxListCtrl within a wxWidgets application, and can't seem to eliminate the flickering that occurs while scrolling through a large list of items quickly (e.g. holding the 'page down' key.)  The list control is created as a virtual/report list, and I'm testing under Win7 at the moment.

It appears the background clear is causing the flickering, though I can't simply override it because it's required for the text/borders to appear correctly.

I believe what I need is a way to do double buffering, where the list isn't updated visually until after both the background is cleared and the items are drawn (offscreen.)  Does anyone know how to do this in wxWidgets?  Or is there a better way?

Many thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Using the VCL version of TListView I call pListView->DoubleBuffered = true; If there is a property under wxWidgets that like you might try it.